# Weka API: Creating a TDM using StringToWordVector

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have the following code:

```
 ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>()
    attributes.add(new Attribute("tweet", true))

    ArrayList<String> theLines = new ArrayList<>()
    File cleanestTweets = new File("cleanestTweets.txt")
    File savedResults = new File("savedResults.arff")
    Instances instances

    try {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(cleanestTweets)

        while (console.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = console.nextLine()

                theLines.add(theLine)

        }

        Instance ins = new DenseInstance(1)
        instances = new Instances("TwitterData", attributes, theLines.size())
        theLines.each { it ->
            ins.setValue(attributes[0], it)
            instances.add(ins)
        }

        StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector()
        filter.setInputFormat(instances)
        filter.setOutputWordCounts(true)
        filter.setTFTransform(true)
        filter.setDictionaryFileToSaveTo(savedResults)
        filter.getDictionaryFileToSaveTo()


    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

The code which creates the instances works fine. I am then trying to create a TDM and write this out to the savedResults.txt. When running the code, there is nothing being written to the savedResults.txt. I'm not entirely sure why. I've read the [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html#setOutputWordCounts-boolean-) but it doesn't mention anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector()
    filter.setInputFormat(instances)
    filter.setDictionaryFileToSaveTo(savedResults)
    filter.setOutputWordCounts(true)
    filter.setTFTransform(true)
    Instances dataFiltered = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(instances, filter)
```

This does write out the words and their occurrences into the file. Looks like you have to create new Instances and explicitly state to use the filter. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811418/java-weka-stringtowordvector-is-not-counting-word-occurences-properly?rq=1) to come to this conclusion.